# lodash remove object from

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a JSON response like this:

```
{ 
  id_order: '123123asdasd',
  products: [ 
    { 
      description: 'Product 1 description',
      comments: [
        { 
          id_comment: 1,
          text: 'comment1'
        },
        { 
          id_comment: 2,
          text: 'comment2'
        }
      ] 
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I remove, with [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs), one object which has an *id_comment* that is equal to 1, for example?

Tried using `_.remove` without success.

### Solution

https://jsfiddle.net/baumannzone/o9yuLuLy/

Comment: when you say "tried using...." show us the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [_.remove](https://lodash.com/docs#remove) inside an forEach using an object as the predicate:

```
_.forEach(obj.products, function(product) {
  _.remove(product.comments, {id_comment: 1});
});
```

> If an object is provided for predicate the created _.matches style callback returns true for elements that have the properties of the given object, else false.

---

```js
var obj = {
  id_order: '123123asdasd',
  products: [{
    description: 'Product 1 description',
    comments: [{
      id_comment: 1,
      text: 'comment1'
    }, {
      id_comment: 2,
      text: 'comment2'
    }]
  }, {
    description: 'Product 2 description',
    comments: [{
      id_comment: 2,
      text: 'comment2'
    }, {
      id_comment: 3,
      text: 'comment3'
    }]
  }, {
    description: 'Product 3 description',
    comments: [{
      id_comment: 1,
      text: 'comment1'
    }, {
      id_comment: 2,
      text: 'comment2'
    }]
  }]
};

_.forEach(obj.products, function(product) {
  _.remove(product.comments, {id_comment: 1});
});

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Yay! It works really well. I was missing using ```forEach```. Thanks!
Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/baumannzone/o9yuLuLy/

Comment: This is the better answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

removeObject: function(collection,property, value){

```
     return   _.reject(collection, function(item){

        return item[property] === value;
    })
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `remove()`:

```
_.each(order.products, function (product) {
    _.remove(product.comments, function (comment) {
        return comment.id_comment === 1;
    });
});
```

Assuming your order variable is named `order`, and the `products` and `comments` properties are always present.